# Add try catch and convert a function to a generic class swift

Tags: ios, swift, tcp, try-catch

In one of my view controllers I have a function to establish a tcp connection , send and receive messages which is as follows.

```
func tcpConnection(host: NSString){
        var client = TCPClient(addr: String(host) as String, port: Config.tcpPort)

        let (success, err) = client.connect(timeout: Config.tcpConnectionTimeout)

        log?.debug("Connected \(success)")
        guard success else { log?.error("Cannot Connect \(err)"); return}

        let (successMsg, failmsg) = client.send(str: self.jsonString)

        let data = client.read(Config.expectedByteLength)
        guard let d = data else { return }

        guard let recievedMsg = String(bytes: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else { return }
        self.recivedMsgFromServer = recievedMsg

        log?.debug("Recieved msg\(recievedMsg)")

        let (clientClosed, errormsg) = client.close()
        guard clientClosed else { return }

    }
```

I am using this piece of code twice in the same view controller. So I want to have a generic class for this function . Also I have many guards which I want to replace with a single try catch block.

Also after receiving a message I am doing different things in both the tcp connection functions.

Following is what I have tried until now.

```
class TcpService{

    var jsonString : String = ""

    func tcpConnection(host: NSString){
        do {

            var client = try TCPClient(addr: String(host) as String, port: Config.tcpPort)   
            let (success, err) = client.connect(timeout: Config.tcpConnectionTimeout)

            log?.debug("Connected \(success)")
            guard success else { log?.error("Cannot Connect \(err)"); return}

            let (successMsg, failmsg) = client.send(str: self.jsonString)

            let data = client.read(Config.expectedByteLength)
            guard let d = data else { return }

            guard let recievedMsg = String(bytes: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else { return }


            log?.debug("Recieved msg\(recievedMsg)")
            /*Do Something different in every viewController
             //For Example
             self.Info = Mapper<Info>().map(recievedMsg)

             log?.debug("Status\(self.Info?.Status)")

             */

            let (clientClosed, errormsg) = client.close()
            guard clientClosed else { return }



        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print(fetchError)
            // Handle Error

        }
    }

}
```

When I try to call this function from the new class in my view controller it does not behave in the same way the function in the view controller did.

Is there anything I should change in the way I have created the class?

Any help will be appreciated as I am very new to swift. Thank you

Comment: I don't think TCPClient class throws any exception. If not, then try catch would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way your problem could be solved. Skip the custom error throwing part if you don't actually need it. The way to refactor it is using callback function, just send your function into this one, i.e.:

```
TCPService.connect("some_host", message: "your_message") { response in
    Mapper<Info>().map(response)
}
```

Code:

```
import Foundation

extension NSError {
    static func error(with localized: String) -> NSError {
        return NSError(domain: "error", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: localized])
    }
}

class TCPService {

    static func connect(host: String, andSend message: String, onComplete: String -> ()) {
        do {
            let client = try TCPClient(addr: host, port: Config.tcpPort)
            let (successfulConnection, error) = client.connect(timeout: Config.tcpConnectionTimeout)

            log?.debug("Connected \(successfulConnection)")
            guard successfulConnection else {
                throw NSError.error(with: error)
                log?.error("Cannot Connect \(error)")
                return
            }

            let (successfullySent, failureMessage) = client.send(str: message)

            let data = client.read(Config.expectedByteLength)
            guard successfullySent,
                let d = data,
                receivedMessage = String(bytes: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
                    throw NSError.error(with: failureMessage)
                    return
            }

            log?.debug("Received msg\(receivedMessage)")
            onComplete(receivedMessage)

            let (clientClosed, errorMessage) = client.close()
            guard clientClosed else {
                throw NSError.error(with: errorMessage)
                return
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print(fetchError)

            // Handle errors
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to get the details in response and print it as follows.  print("Response TCP",response) But when I try to print value from the Info class I get a nil log?.debug("Status\(self.Info?.Status)")

Comment: I don't know, but are you sure you want it to be called in the completion block, as it has nothing to do with the `receivedMessage` obtained from server.

Comment: Yes , I want to set boolean flags and update my UI only after I recieve a message from the server. Is there anything wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Yes, this is the proper way to do this, just make sure you do all your UI stuff on the main thread. About the `self.Info?.Status` being nil, I don't know, if you could provide some more information I could help